# React inline styling with multiple inputs

Tags: reactjs

How would we implement something like "padding: 0 10px" for inline styling on a React element? It throws an error if I give the padding or margin properties the shortcut syntax, so I have to explicitly declare paddingTop, paddingRight, etc. I don't see anything on the React docs to address this, so I'm wondering if it's possible to use the shortcut in React?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide us with a [mcve], showing your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible you just probably have a typo or accidentally wrote it wrong. The syntax to apply an inline style follows this pattern.

`{{property: 'value'}}`
**you can't add a semi colon in the value for a property.**

inline styles are denoted as an object for react. and the syntax to apply a property or read something as javascript in the react render method is also denoted with curly braces.

So to apply that to your specific question, you would just do this.

```
<div style={{margin: '0px 10px'}} />
```

if you are using a style variable that is defined before the return of your render function you can use it like so.

```
const divStyles = {
    margin: '0px 10px'
}

// ... in the render return

<div style={divStyles} />
```

[Sample Fiddle with shortcut padding and margin used](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/75572/)